# Display multiple values from field Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, field

Hello I am using the following code to display a custom field in a user profile.  However I can only get it to display one value at a time.  How can I extract multiple values from the field?  The field is set up as an unlimited integer field.  Each value is on it own row.

```
<?php
    global $user;
    $user_data = user_load($user->uid);
    $test = $user_data->field_companies['und']['0']['value'];
    echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($user_data->field_companies['und'] as $val) {
    // Do something with $val
}
```

Comment: Tried the following.  But it returns Array Array Array instead of the actual values 28 35 48

Comment: Are you forgetting about `['value']` ? `echo $val['value']`

Answer (score 2):

The proper method is to use the [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function:

```
$items = field_get_items('user', $user_data, 'field_companies');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $val = $item['value'];
}
```

Running through the raw value array is dangerous as it ignores language considerations.